# How to assign a new value to a column with "OR" in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the follwoing dataframe called `Grades`:

```
    Name    Grade
0   Ron     100
1   Dana    69
2   Bob     77
3   Dan     32
4   John    99
5   Brita   115
```

I want to create a new column (called "Love") and in this new column to assign a boolean of value "true" to the rows of "Dana" and "John" - since they are the two people which I love. So the outcome should be:

```
    Name    Grade  LOVE
0   Ron    100      False
1   Dana    69      True
2   Bob     77      False
3   Dan     32      False
4   John    99      True
5   Brita   115     False
```

I tried this code but it did not work:

```
Grades['Love'] = Grades.Name == ('Marie' | 'John')
```

How to use the "Or" assignment correctly?

Comment: this seems to be a biased teacher grading students based on arbitrary personal preferences 

Comment: upload your original csv (as text or file) and then I can help. What you need can be done with built-in python libraries without pandas.

Comment: `Grades['Love']=Grades['Name'].isin(['Dana','John'])`

Comment: Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
Grades['Love'] = Grades.Name.isin(['Dana', 'John'])
```

Here is the result:

```
    Name    Grade   Love
0   Ron     100     False
1   Dana    69      True
2   Bob     77      False
3   Dan     32      False
4   John    99      True
5   Brita   115     False
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide the output included in the answer? I like your approach the most, it's easy to read.

Comment: @thenarfer, added the resulting DataFrame.

Comment: @SergeiLazarevich But looking mess.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isin`, to check for multiple values

```py
>>> df.assign(LOVE=df['Name'].isin(['Dana',  'John']))

    Name  Grade   LOVE
0    Ron    100  False
1   Dana     69   True
2    Bob     77  False
3    Dan     32  False
4   John     99   True
5  Brita    115  False
```

If you want to use `OR`, you need to combine the series of truthfulness for each individual values by `OR` i.e. `|`:

```py
>>> df.assign(LOVE=(df['Name']=='Dana')|(df['Name']=='John'))

    Name  Grade   LOVE
0    Ron    100  False
1   Dana     69   True
2    Bob     77  False
3    Dan     32  False
4   John     99   True
5  Brita    115  False
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this :

```py
>>> Grades["Love"]=Grades["Name"].str.contains("Dana|John")
>>> Grades
    Name  Grade   Love
0    Ron    100  False
1   Dana     69   True
2    Bob     77  False
3    Dan     32  False
4   John     99   True
5  Brita    115  False
```

As you said `Grades` is DataFrame. For more information about `str.contains()` you may visit [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).